# Xcode SDK IOS 4.2 installation and missing iOS 4.1 in build settings

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ios-4.2

i have download Xcode SDK 4.2(xcode_3.2.5_and_ios_sdk_4.2_final.dmg) from Apple developer site and installed successfully .  when open my old xcode project it shows baseSDk missing ,when i try to change project setting ,i have found and set base SDk as 4.2 it works fine

```
 my problem is ,in Base SDk list it shows
```

(iOS 2.1, iOS 2.2,  iOS 2.2.1,  iOS 3.0, iOS 3.1, iOS 3.1.2, iOS 3.1.3, iOS 4.2)

There is no **iOS 4.0** and **iOS 4.1** (which i have used before 4.2). anything wrong in my installation???? Plz help me to correct my mistake

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does happen. I generally just use the latest SDK as base SDK. You support the latest version and forget abt the older versions[apple style]. This way your app can take advantage of all the latest functionality.

One thing you must remember is that the Base SDK is different from the deployment target.
base SDK is the latest SDK your project will use and support.
deployment target is found in target->getInfo; this is the minimum version that your app will support.
4.2 is a free upgrade and most of them would upgrade, so i'd set the deployment target as 4.0 or at the least 3.0. who uses 2.x anymore?

if you really want 4.0 and 4.1 as well, you have to install the old 4.1 GM as a parallel Xcode IDE or follow this link and get support for all the versions in a single XCode IDE.

http://chris-fletcher.com/2010/08/28/howto-install-iphone-sdk-2-0-3-1-for-xcode-3-2/

I'd suggest building using 4.2 but follow the link and install all the simulator SDKs for old versions so that you can test the app on those versions of the simulator.

Comment: thanks lot ,now am clear about the versions as well as clear about  base SDK and target version.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing went wrong here. That's how Apple forces the developers to always use the latest SDK to develop.

Comment: oh!!! Thanks diwup .but still some of the lowest base SDKs are displaying like ( OS 2.1, iOS 2.2, iOS 2.2.1, iOS 3.0, iOS 3.1, iOS 3.1.2, iOS 3.1.3 ) ?

Comment: but when you compile, can you use those lower SDKs?

Comment: in my Xcode, I cannot find any lower SDKs, I'm a little confused.